# After writing selenium test cases and integrating them with ANT, where can i see the results?

Tags: selenium

I wrote a few selenium test cases for testing a web application and then integrated the testcases using ANT build automation tool using build.xml.

The output comes to the reports folder, but how can I see the results for all the testcases that I wrote?

Comment: Are you using a test framework such as JUnit or TestNG?

Comment: TestNG framework and some times Junit framework also

Comment: I find your question a bit confusing.  You ask where to "see" the results, but you clearly state that the output goes into the reports folder.  So you know where the reports are, what can't you "see"

Answer (score 1):

There must be an `Index.html` file in the result directory. After execution you can see the execution result in that file. Open the file in any of the available browser, or refresh that if already opened.

If you are using xslt reporting, you can get the result in index.html file of `test-output` directory.

Comment: There are other html files such as alltest-fails, alltests-errors, all-tests.. please tell me what these files are? Can we see failed tests in alltests-fails and all the errors in alltests-errors?

Comment: @Sudha...Two things... first...It that so much difficult that you could not check it by your own? and second, if you are asking any question not same as the raised one, you should raise a separate thread for it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps in your build.xml ?  I haven't tried this but I assume "frames" means HTML frames output?

```
<target name="test-reports" depends="test">
    <junitreport tofile="TESTS-TestSuites.xml" todir="${junit.output.dir}/reports">
        <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <include name="**/reports/*TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}/reports" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
</project>
```

Personally, I think Maven or Gradle is a better way to do it than Ant but then again I haven't used Ant and so perhaps I cannot judge.

Comment: Yeah above is the ANT build.xml, But here am not confused with build.xml. I wanted to know how to view the results after the testcases are run through ANT.